# Understanding javascript code return componet.extend({}); in magento 2

Tags: magento2, javascript, knockoutjs, requirejs

I am new in magento 2 and requireJS
Can someone explain to me what "return componet.extend({}); " means when I am trying to add new JS module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means you are returning some object which extends another object, which is using as a prototype for your object. This object has parent which is stored in the `component` variable. In case when you assign this component to some html-element (see [`mage-init` docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_init.html)) this element will be recognized as a component on the page, with all defined in this component and its parents properties and methods. In this case the Magento will initialize your component during page rendering.

It is not necessary to always return a component. If you want to add just plain javascript you may return whatever you want - function, property or nothing.

To learn more about the UI-components and JavaScript in magento I recommend you to read [the great articles series](http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_introducing_ui_components/) writen by [Alan Strom](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/4/alan-storm).